# SQL posting the result of an in page query to the db

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 bits of code which are both doing what they are supposed to:

**A)** This code shows and updates the field in the database based on the value in the input field

```
<input id="input" class="input-small" type="text" name='C_N_C' value="<?php if(isset($_POST['C_N_C'])) echo $_POST['C_N_C']; else echo $C_N_C; ?>">
```

**B)** This code counts the values in another db and returns the number or rows

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT COUNT(C_ID) FROM CfortoC WHERE C_ID = '{$_GET['id']}'";
$results = mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($results);
echo $rows[0];
?>
```

Individually these work fine!

**What I need to do is to run the query FIRST then have that value displayed in the input box.  Then when "UPDATE" is clicked to update the C_N_C value to that of the query! **

I hope that makes sense!  Thanks for any help!

**MORE CODE**

As requested here is more code!

```
 <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="input">C Label </label>
      <div class="controls">
      <input id="input" class="input-small" type="text" name='C_N_C' value="<?php if(isset($_POST['C_N_C'])) echo $_POST['C_N_C']; else echo $C_N_C; ?>">

 <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) { ?>

 <?php 
      $query = "SELECT COUNT(C_ID) FROM CfortoC WHERE C_ID = '{$_GET['id']}'";
      $results = mysql_query($query);
      $rows = mysql_fetch_array($results);
      echo $rows[0];
 ?>

 <?php } ?>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the part you are having trouble with?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am having trouble combining them together

Comment: Can you post the complete code? It would help a lot to see these in context.

Comment: I'm not a php programmer, but if this was ColdFusion, you would have to give an alias to count(c_id) in your query.

Comment: @larsAnders I have added more code for you, sorry you need to scroll to the right to see it all.  Thanks Dan, I tried searching how to do that in an sql query within a post statement but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You're making a lot of mistakes here: Using `mysql_query`, not [properly escaping your data](http://bobby-tables.com/) and having very little in the way of organization. A [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) makes it a lot easier to get started since it will give you a foundation to build off of, and has many examples on how to implement certain things. Instead of working up from first principles, which is very tedious and error-prone, work with tested, proven code and build your logic on top.

Comment: @tadman Yep! I 100% agree!  However I am not a php mysql programmer. I was working with a guy that built the bulk of this and then who dropped me in it COMPLETELY!  I am now left with a looming deadline with no support and no knowledge to complete the work!  I have been managing by learning from existing code that is available to me in the system and adapting it.  Not ideal by ANY means but it is all I can do in my situation unfortunately.

Comment: It'll be risky to deploy that code as-is since it's riddled with SQL injection bugs and XSS issues. At the very least you need to add `mysql_real_escape_string` on inputs that are part of your query, and `htmlspecialchars` when calling `echo` on user data. This is super annoying to do, which is why a framework is a big win here, most have ways of doing it more effortlessly. As to your problem here, you're not checking for errors.

Comment: This will only be used internally on an in house server so that isn't too much of an issue.  Sorry, I am a total php mysql noob.  What do you mean I am not checking for errors?

Comment: In the question you say "when `UPDATE` is clicked" but I don't see an update button or link anywhere in the code --- ?

Comment: That is further down my page, the page is around 1000 lines.  It is just a standard submit button.  Can the above (A) & (B) code that I posted be combined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for. The first time through the page, the input will display the value of `$C_N_C`, which is the result of the `SELECT COUNT` statement (provided there is a value for `$_GET['id']`). When a user enters data into that field and submits the form, the second time around `$_POST['C_N_C']` will be set, and the input will display that value instead.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(C_ID) FROM CfortoC WHERE C_ID = '{$id}'";
    $results = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($results);
    $C_N_C = $rows[0];
} 

if(isset($_POST['C_N_C'])){
    $C_N_C = htmlspecialchars($_POST['C_N_C']);
}

?>

<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="input">C Label </label>
    <div class="controls">

    <input id="input" class="input-small" type="text" name="C_N_C" value="<?php echo $C_N_C; ?>">

    </div>
</div>
```

Also, mysql_ functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5. 
You should make the switch to [mysqli functions](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Awesome!! That did the trick!! Thank you very much for your help @larsAnders!  Believe me this is a one off project!  I am not touching php & mysql again! Haha!